# About CSS margin width JQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to control margin with JQuery, for example, if Paragraph has class "mt60" without **.mt60{margin-top:60px;}**, Paragraph has margin-top:60px. is only controlled by JQuery.

https://codepen.io/selucky/pen/BaypmaM

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<p class="mt60 ml30">Lorem ipsum</p>
```

```js
$("[class*='mt'], [class*='mb'], [class*='ml'], [class*='mr']").each(function(){

        var margin = $(this);
            num = $(margin).attr("class").match(/\d+0/);
            result = num + "px";

        if($("*").is(margin) + num){

            if($(margin).is("[class*='mt']")){
                $(this).css("margin-top", result);
            }

            if($(margin).is("[class*='mb']")){
                $(this).css("margin-bottom", result);
            }

            if($(margin).is("[class*='ml']")){
                $(this).css("margin-left", result);
            }

            if($(margin).is("[class*='mr']")){
                $(this).css("margin-right", result);
            }
        }
    });
```

Why this Paragraph's margin-left is 60px?

I don't want the answer, only I want is the hint or the keyword for a search.

I tried search many times and may ways that "regular expression", "exec()", "text()", "filter()", various attribute selectors, etc..

Comment: The `each` function will not loop over the same element multiple times, it will find the element with the class `mt60 ml30` once, which matches your selector. `result` then is `60` as `mt60` it the first class in the list. You would need to loop over the classList in order to get the different number values per element

Comment: empiric/thank you very much.